# "Unexpected character '�' (1:0)" occurs by uploading local image in Next.js

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I am importing a local image in my project and i used two different ways to import the image in my Next App

1.

```
 <img src={required("../image/—Pngtree—blue stock trading graph_6050459")} alt="hell" />
```

2. ```
    import logo from "../image/—Pngtree—blue stock trading graph_6050459.png";
    <img src={logo} alt="hell" /> // Using logo in image tag
   ```

[image: directtory]

however i succesfully reach the directory having my image but i dont know why it is not loading and it shows me this error message

[image]

i also use 'next/image' but still dont get any results

the solution of the problem is how can i use local image in my project.

Is this image related problem or it is an other type of Problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Next.js we store images in the public folder. That's where we store static assets like images or fonts
Look at this [example](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/static-file-serving) for reference on how to add images from public folder using the next/image component

Comment: thanks brother. I was having my image in other folder but when i put the image in "public" folder then it load